# Write a value near a coordinate in a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, external-files, metadata

I want to do it from a file, rather from inside the document like I do it now:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title = My title,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        legend entries = {A},
    ]
    \addplot [nodes near coords, mark = *, blue, point meta = explicit symbolic] %table {Measurements/A.dat};
    table[meta = label] {
        x     y    label
        0    10  0
        0.1  9   0.1
        0.5  6   0.5
        0.9  5   0.9
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My file is like this, but I am OK in changing the format if needed:

```
x_0 f(x) label
# some comment line
0    10  0
0.1  9   0.1
0.5  6   0.5
0.9  5   0.9
```

In other words, I want to just write

`table {Measurements/A.dat};`

and have my data in `A.dat` file, instead of writing the data inside the `.tex`:

```
table[meta = label] {
  x     y    label
  0     10   0
  ...
};
```

Is this possible? Could not find the solution in the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

`table`

with

`table[meta = label]`

and you should be fine.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}
  x_0 f(x) label
  %some comment
0    10  0
0.1  9   0.1
0.5  6   0.5
0.9  5   0.9
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title = My title,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        legend entries = {A},
        every node near coord/.append style={anchor=south west},
    ]
    \addplot [nodes near coords, mark = *, blue, point meta = explicit symbolic] %table {Measurements/A.dat};
    table[meta = label] {mydata.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did the trick. I edited your answer, but it is peer reviewed, hope you do not mind. :)

Comment: @G.Samaras Feel free. :-)